# LOVE2D Graphics are not working

Tags: 10.04, ati, graphics, programming, lua

I `sudo apt-get`ted (grammar ftw) LOVE2D Lua API, and when I try to run a game on my machine, it doesn't work at all. When I use a simple `love.graphics.print("Hello, World!")` I get a blank screen, and I try re-creating the font and this still does nothing. HOWEVER, LOVE2D still works for me on my other computer with MS-Windows 7. The Terminal output doesn't help at all, everything is showing up fine. AND, when I use a conf.lua file to manually set the title to something, it doesn't work. Would that be because of dependency errors? Or am I maybe missing a driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this googling, so I might be a bit late to the party, but it says you're using 10.04, which means that the ubuntu repositories ship a very outdated version of love.

My ppa (the official one) `ppa:bartbes/love-stable` provides up to 0.7.1, which, too is outdated. I have, however, heard that the dependency that was once lacking, might be available in 10.04 now, using the backports, so it might be worth grabbing a newer deb and seeing whether that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I'm a little later than you :D). As of now, the guys at `love.org` provide a .DEB package for download, and the newest version is now in the main repositories.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you would also have to put the coordinates, something like:

```
love.graphics.print("dsfdsfds",100,100)
```